# Programmatically set the image of a panel to a jpg file that is not in resources?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

How can I programmatically set the image of a panel to a jpg file (a non BMP), that is not in resources?

I know how to set it to a BMP file(not in resources) or a resource file, but how to set it to a JPG file (not in resources)?

Comment: Load the image from file and then set it as panel background.

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever between loading any of the supported image formats. Why didn't you simply try?

Comment: @TaW  I thought `this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"c:\Temp\image.bmp");` ( which was the method I had seen previously), was just for BMP format  because it had `new Bitmap(..)` in it  But turns out it doesn't just mean MS's BMP format but works for jpg and png too (which are technically bitmap formats as well, as opposed to vector based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Image.FromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Image.FromStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream(v=vs.110).aspx) to load the image and then set it as background image of the panel:

```
this.panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"d:\image.jpg");
```